# Cannot use JavaScript inside PDF with Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, pdf, javascript

I am having troubles using JavaScript in a PDF file opened with Firefox.

To sum up, it is a file that uses XFA forms and JavaScript to validate the form and generate a QrCode. Here is the link to the file:
[IRCC Form](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5257e.pdf)

It just tells me:

```
JavaScript has been disabled, the form requires JavaScript to validate properly.
Please enable JavaScript through Preferences under the Edit menu and reopen the form.
```

I checked my `about:config` in firefox. I have my

```
pdfjs.disable : false  
pdfjs.enableScripting : true  
javascript.enabled : true
```

I can fill in the form but the *Validate* button does nothing. I even tried with Chrome and it doesn't work.

Please help me, I don't want to go back to Windows with Adobe Acrobat Reader. I left that dark past behind me :( ...

Comment: Did you search to see if there are any Ubuntu compatible PDF readers?

Comment: I've used Ubuntu for many years, but I also use a dual-boot system with Microsoft Windows.  Even if you want to put it behind you, sometimes, the people you interact with have not and you have to use it.  It has a majority share of the personal computer market; no matter how "dark" you think it is, you/we cannot deny it...

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/pdf-viewer-list-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: I tried Okular and Atril, I read online that evince is not compatible with JS but I will try it anyways ...

Comment: Evince does not even open the file, Okular does not support forms ...

Comment: @wil123 did you try to validate them on signature panel?

Comment: what does that mean, can you develop please ?

Comment: @wil123 please check my initial answer

Comment: Hi @wil123, have you solved the problem? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have Adobe for Ubuntu, you can follow this to install Adobe Reader 9 on i386

```
wget --progress=dot -O ~/adobe.deb ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt install libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -i ~/adobe.deb
acroread /path/file.pdf
```

to **enable JavaScript support** follow :

Edit > Preferences > JavaScript > Checkmark Enable Acrobat JavaSript and Checkmark Enable JavaScript Security

and then, to **validate the signature** follow :

View > Navigation Panels > Click Signatures > on the left panel click Validate All button to accept all certified by IRCC

after you fill the form, click the validate button and it will appears the notification JS like below :

[image]

and then, the QRcode should be appears on the last page like below :

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I followed exactly the same steps as your suggestion, but the validate part is still not working. I first downloaded the page to local then opened with Adobe Reader as you mentioned. Seems like those dynamic features of the form is gone during downloading. What else can I do to edit it properly?